# Why do we multiply by 10 when changing the subject of a formula with logarithms?

Tags: logarithms, arithmetic

I have an equation such as,

$$\ln(t) = -7.5 + 1.5\ln(d)$$

When needing to make $d$ the subject, online calculators multiply both sides by $10$.

Why do we multiply by $10$? I know that the base of $ln$ is 10 when it does not state a base.

Comment: No, the base of $\ln$ is always $e$. 

The base of $\log$, when not stated, is assumed to be $10$.

Comment: @SakethMalyala when not stated, $\log$ is usually base $e$ in mathematics. It's only usually 10 in physical applications because we decided to count by 10... it makes much more sense mathematically to focus on $e$, which has the nicest logarithm.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by online calculators multiply by ten.  Which calculators? I imagine the do it to get rid of decimals.  It doesn't really matter so far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is to make those rational coefficients integers -- and is just the equivalent of clearing fractions, which is just to simplify the equation, so we now have

$$10\ln t=-75+15\ln d,$$ which simplifies further to $$2\ln t=-15+3\ln d.$$

PS. Your last sentence is wrong. The ugly notation $\ln$ is sometimes used to denote the logarithm when the base is a certain real number universally called $e.$ This may be given by the $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{1/k!}.$

Comment: Thank you so much